# How to Calculate number of steps needed in model.predict_generator()

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, theano

So I am trying to figure out this issue of getting less length of Numpy array when I run my model. I have a total of 2000 images which is divided into 2 categories of 1000 each. Now when I pass these images through my vgg16 model for feature extraction it passes me only 1998 images back. Following is my code.

VGG16 model

```
def load_vgg16(weights_path='vgg16.h5'):
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    inputShape = (3, 256, 256)
else:
    inputShape = (256, 256, 3)
model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape = inputShape))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

if weights_path:
    model.load_weights(weights_path, by_name= True)

return model
```

Feature extraction through bottleneck feature:

```
def save_bottleneck_features(location):
batch_size = 16
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1./255)
model = load_vgg16()


generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(location+'/training-data/',
                                       target_size=(image_width, image_height),
                                       batch_size = 16,
                                       class_mode = None,
                                       shuffle = False)
bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(
    generator, nb_training_samples / batch_size)
np.save(open(location+'/bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'wb'), bottleneck_features_train)    

# repeat with the validation data
generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(location+'/validation-data/',
                                       target_size=(image_width, image_height),
                                       batch_size=16,
                                       class_mode=None,
                                       shuffle=False)
bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(
    generator, nb_validation_samples / batch_size)
np.save(open(location+'/bottleneck_features_validation.npy', 'wb'), bottleneck_features_validation)
```

running the above functions:

```
top_model_weights_path='/top_model_weights.h5'

location = 'newdata'
nb_epoch = 50

training_samples= [len(os.listdir('newdata/training-data'+'/'+i)) 
                   for i in sorted(os.listdir('newdata/training-data/'))]
nb_training_samples = sum(training_samples)

#Calucalating number of data prsent in the folders or damage and whole cars in validation folder
validation_samples = [len(os.listdir('newdata/validation-data/' + i)) 
                      for i in sorted(os.listdir('newdata/validation-data/'))]
nb_validation_samples = sum(validation_samples)

print(training_samples)
print(validation_samples)
save_bottleneck_features('newdata')
```

So when I run the above code, I am expecting the total length of the array `bottleneck_features_train` to be 2000 but I am getting 1998 only. Similarly, the total length of `bottleneck_features_validation` comes 1840 but I am expecting to get 1840 (927+909).
The output for `training_samples` and `validation_samples` is below.

```
[1000, 1000]
[927, 909]
```

I think I am passing the wrong number of steps required in `model.predict_generator()`. When I am trying to label these images by using this code.

```
training_data = np.load(open(location+'/bottleneck_features_train.npy','rb'))
training_label = np.array([0] * training_samples[0] +
                          [1] * training_samples[1])

validation_data = np.load(open(location+'/bottleneck_features_validation.npy','rb'))
validation_label = np.array([0] * validation_samples[0] +
                           [1] * validation_samples[1])
```

and try to fit the model then I receive this error about training data and training labels are n not of the same length.

How can I fix this problem and start fitting my model? Thanks for any help. Cheers!

Comment: Try not giving the number of steps, in latest keras versions the ImageDataGenerator is a Sequence so predict_generator can automatically infer the number of batches.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! The only extra problem was the image format. The images I had in my folder was in .jfif and .webp format. I had to convert those too and after that, it worked great.